# create spooledFile from jtopen

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

I try to create a spooledfile with the library jt400.

I have done the program which list the spool in a outqueue without problem but when i want to create the SpooledFile object, my as400 return me an error

> com.ibm.as400.access.ServerStartupException: Not able to pass
>   connection to server job.  Server job timed out.

I don't understand why. Is there something to do on os400 about the security.
Thanks to help me.

Comment: Are you running native on the IBM i server, or is it running on a remote client system?

Comment: jt400 requires to talk to several network ports on the host which must be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the stack trace. JT400 may require PRINT host service for spooled file operations. On IBM i, check if QNPSERVD job is present (`wrkjob QNPSERVD`) if not use `STRHOSTSVR *netprt` to start. Also check that the print server port (default is 8474 for plain connection and 9474 for encrypted) is accessible from your Java server.